# Dependency injection error message

Tags: c#

I am learning dependency injection with a small example. I am getting the error message "object reference not set to an instance of an object" from the ProcessOrder() method below on this line:

```
_iordProc.ProcessOrder(popOrder);
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to provide a parameterless constructor?

Here is my code...

```
public interface IOrderProcessingEngine
{
    void ProcessOrder(Order objOrder);
    void EmailOrder(Order objEmailOrd);
}

public class Order
{
    public String OrderId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public String  OrderDate { get; set; }
    public String DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProcessingEngine : IOrderProcessingEngine
{
    public void ProcessOrder(Order objOrder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This method will process my order which is very cool");
    }

    public void EmailOrder(Order objEmailOrd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This method will send email to the customers");
    }
}

public class OrderService
{
    //Dependency Injection
    private readonly IOrderProcessingEngine _iordProc;

    public OrderService(IOrderProcessingEngine objOrdproc)
    {
        _iordProc = objOrdproc;
    }

    public OrderService()
    {

    }

    public void ProcessOrder(Order popOrder)
    {
        //Getting an error here on next line -- object reference not set to an instance of an object
        _iordProc.ProcessOrder(popOrder);
        _iordProc.EmailOrder(popOrder);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Order myOrder = new Order();
        myOrder.OrderId = "1001";
        myOrder.Amount = 2000;
        myOrder.OrderDate = "05/22/2015";
        myOrder.DeliveryDate = "05/30/2015";
        myOrder.FirstName = "Johnson";
        myOrder.LastName = "Adoga";

        OrderService objOrdServ = new OrderService();
        objOrdServ.ProcessOrder(myOrder);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you plan to do this in production, you may want to consider using a DI framework like [Autofac](http://autofac.org) or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes, that will definitely fail, since you are using the constructor with no parameters:

```
OrderService objOrdServ = new OrderService();
```

So `_iordProc` will always be null when used in that manner. Either pass the parameter, or use an IoC framework that will do the instantiation for you.

```
var objOrdServ = new OrderService(new OrderProcessingEngine());
```

IoC is usually accomplished using other frameworks, such as [AutoFac](http://autofac.org/) or [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), to name a few.

Comment: IoC containers are a great help, but since the OP is just learning about dependency injection, it's not a bad thing to do it manually in the beginning.

Comment: Yup, totally agree. That's why I showed the way to instantiate it manually, as well as mention a few frameworks to check out.

Comment: I thought the idea of dependency injection is not to allow Class A depend on Class B. Will doing this var objOrdServ = new OrderService(new OrderProcessingEngine()); not break the rule ??

Comment: Right, but since you don't have a factory that would provide an instance only based on its interface contract then they end up being explicit in your example. Usually IoC containers handle that. Your classes end up depending on interface contracts, and when instantiating, the container will get the correct instance based on what you registered within it.

If you had some sort of factory class, that returned a `IOrderProcessingEngine` then they would be decoupled again.

Answer (score 1):

For dependency injection, you still need to actually inject the dependant object.

Where you have

```
OrderService objOrdServ = new OrderService();
```

in your code, you need to provide an instance of `OrderProcessingEngine` - you have a constructor that takes a parameter of the base interface type, so if you do

```
OrderService objOrdServ = new OrderService(new OrderProcessingEngine());
```

then the `_iordProc` class variable will reference an instance of your required class.

Edit: I put the wrong code lines in my answer - corrected now.

Comment: His `Order` class doesn't have a constructor like that, did you mean `OrderService`?

Comment: @neontapir Yes, I was in a hurry and completely put the wrong code, but thought I'd spotted it and corrected it before anyone would notice. I see the tapir has faster reactions than I!